# Mongodb search in Document and subDocument through single query

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I have a document with an array sub-document

I need to search on document and sub-document ***through a single query***

I need results only of the sub-document array data, passing the criteria

Sample Data [2 documents]

```
{
  _id : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"),
  name: David,
  list: [
    {
      sport: basketball,
      score: 100
    },
    {
      sport: cricket,
      score: 30
    }
    {
      sport: rugby,
      score: 100
    }
    ]
},

{
  _id : ObjectId("879e28664815cbfcb21622g9"),
  name: Shawn,
  list: [
    {
      sport: basketball,
      score: 100
    },
    {
      sport: cricket,
      score: 50
    }
    {
      sport: rugby,
      score: 20
    }
    ]
}
```

*Expected Result*

List of games in which David's score is 100

- Document query **name = David**
- Sub-document query **score = 100**

**Response: [basketball, rugby]**

---

Query tried but getting NULL is result

```
findOne({name:'David', "list.score": 100})
```

Comment: Try `findOne({name:'David', list: { $elemMatch: {score: 100} })`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That returned me the whole document.. with list bearing !=100 scores too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation pipeline.

- For name use a simple `$match`
- For the array use the `$filter` function

Would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { name: "David" } },
  {
    $set: {
      list: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$list",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$this.score", 100] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: will that be a double $ at cond ??

Comment: Yes, `$$this` is the default variable name. See [$filter()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) and [Variables in Aggregation Expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/index.html)

Comment: This is working at my MongoDB compass.. but when I put this at code.. not giving result !!!

Comment: Can you suggest me condition, if instead of score, I would had scoreId

Comment: ScoreId would be ObjectId ..somehow $eq is not working in case with ObjectId comparison

Comment: Please show your query, it should work in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

to get the List of games in which David's score is 100 you shoud do :

```
const user = await User.findOne({name:'David'}) 
if (user){
    const games = user.list.filter(el => el.score === 100)
    console.log(games)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html#elemmatch-projection) projection operator to limit the elements of the array:

```
await User.findOne({name:'David', 'list.score': 100}).select({list:{$elemMatch:{score:100}})
```

That example document doesn't seem to be showing quotation marks around the strings.

Note that `{score:100}` will only match if the value is numeric, i.e. it will not match `{sport: "basketball", score:"100"}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer...but this is returning me only one record of sub document.. I need all the elements of array being equal to 100

Answer (score 0):

Just a topup to the ACCEPTED ANSWER

that match and set aggregation code can be produced from MongoDB compass too

Compass' Aggregations tab --> Export to language button